# Can't set cookie in the request

Tags: java, testing, junit, rest-assured

I'm using rest-assured library for the API tests and it seems like a new cookie can't be set. I can however modify the cookie which is set by the server.

```
given()
  .cookie("cookie1", "true")
  .get(url)
  .then()
  .assertThat().cookie("cookie1", "true");
// Fails with "Cookie "cookie1" was not
// defined in the response. Cookies are: cookie2=true, cookie3=true


given()
  .cookie("cookie2", "false")
  .get(url)
  .then()
  .assertThat().cookie("cookie2", "false");
// PASS
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [REST-assured Documentation](https://code.google.com/p/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#Cookies), you need to call the `when()` and `body()` methods:

```
given()
.cookie("cookie1", "true")
.when() // <----
.get(url)
.then()
.assertThat()
.body(equalTo("true")) // <----
```

Please note that I have never used this API and I'm just speculating based on the provided specification.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it but this is not a problem. `when()` is just syntactic sugar and `body` is for asserting response body. Response cookie are asserted as in my original post, see https://code.google.com/p/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#Verifying_Response_Data

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this

```
given().
                proxy(host("http.proxy.someDomain.com").withScheme("http").withPort(xxxx)).
```

Comment: Can you give some reasoning along with voting down?